# How to load an NSDictionary from a file created with writeToFile?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary, and I wrote it using

```
[stuff writeToFile:@"TEST" atomically:YES];
```

How can I retrieve it in the future?

Also, what would happen if I decide to replace my iPhone 4 with the 4S? Can my piece of written data be transferred?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT in 2022/03: changed initWithContentsofFile to initWithContentsOfFile**

I think you want something like:

```
[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];
```

You do need to obtain the correct path to store and retrieve your file, along the lines of this routine:

```
- (NSString *)dataFilePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TEST"];
}
```

Comment: Probably this, but I am getting "null".

Comment: Are you setting the data path of your file?  I assumed you had that part covered, but you do need to get the correct path for your file.  I've added some code that you can use.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define a path to write to. If you use `[stuff writeToFile:@"TEST" atomically:YES];` in the iPhone simulator it will write a file called TEST in your home directory of your Mac. Use this code to save to the Documents folder in the simulator and on the iPhone

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
            NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
```

Here is the code you need to read and write files.

```
-(void)writeFileToDisk:(id)stuff
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
            NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = @"TEST";

    NSString *fileAndPath = [documentDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    [stuff writeToFile:fileAndPath atomically:YES];
}

-(void)readFileFromDisk
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
            NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = @"TEST";

    NSString *fileAndPath = [documentDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSArray *stuff = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileAndPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",stuff);
    [stuff release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to store your Dictionary like this:

```
[[NSUserDefalts standardUserDefaults] setObject:myDictionary forKey:@"myKey"];
```

And later you can retrieve it like this:

```
[[NSUserDefalts standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

Also nothing will happen if you use the same code with an iPhone 4 or an iPhone 4S.

Answer (score 0):

A Swift solution

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let filePath = (documentsPath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.txt")

if let data = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
}
```