# Is it possible to read and update settings plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Just a quick question. I am bit unsure about this.

When I add a Settings.plist to my Objective C iPhone project and read the settings from it. Is it possible to update settings in this file? Or is this file only readable and should I create a copy at another location like this:

`NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);`

and check for its existence at launch?

Comment: Refer [Updating & changing settings plist files with new versions of an app][1] link.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609305/updating-changing-settings-plist-files-with-new-versions-of-an-app

Comment: about which plist you are asking ?? is it a project's plist (<appname>-info.plist)???

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029426/how-to-load-an-nsdictionary-from-a-file-created-with-writetofile/8030445#8030445

Comment: It appears to me that I may not change the project's plist. I now implemented it to have the defaults and I override it with a runtime created user settings plist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit the files you included in your app through Xcode, so you could copy it to the user's document folder.

However, as you're interested in a settings plist file, I advise you to save the settings using NSUserDefaults, which automatically saves a .plist file: In the app's delegate on applicationDidFinishLoading write

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![defaults boolForKey:@"firstRunComplete"]) {
    [defaults setObject:optionOne forKey:@"optionOne"]; //replace
    [defaults setObject:optionTwo forKey:@"optionTwo"]; //replace
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"firstRunComplete"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

And when you want to change one of the options

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:optionOne forKey:@"optionOne"]; //replace
[defaults setObject:optionTwo forKey:@"optionTwo"]; //replace
[defaults synchronize];
```

Alternatively you can use this method for editing plist files:

```
NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
[plistDict writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];
```